WinUi how get value from passed parameter by ContentFrame.Navigate
For my NavigationView control I am using method ItemInvoked="NavView_ItemInvoked". And in C# I do:
ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(PlayersPage), _context);

Where _context is my DbContext.
I am looking for a way that I can use this DbContext on the PlayersPage. How can I download my DbContext in PlayersPage?
I also use dependency injection. I tried but I also can't find a way to inject DbContext into PlayersPage.
Whenever I create a constructor other than default it throws an error:

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
instance of an object.'
GameTools.MyApp_XamlTypeInfo.XamlUserType.Activator.get
returned null.

in method ActivateInstance() during run ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(PlayersPage), _context);
How can I download my parameter pass by Navigate method in PlayersPage?
How should I pass my DbContext to the PlayersPage?

Also see Page.OnNavigatedTo. Are there any questions about this?

You can get the Navigatemethod's parameter by overriding the OnNavigatedTo method:
public sealed partial class Page1 : Page
{
    public Page1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        if (e.Parameter is DbContext dbContext)
        {
        }
    }
}

