How to share data between pages when using frame according to MVVM
I have a simple application with a frame in a MainPage.xaml that changes between MediaCenterPage.xaml and PlayerPage.xaml. Now I want the selected movie in the MediaCenter to be shared with the PlayerPage. If I use a binding and refer to the model it is of course two different instances of the object. What is the proper approach to share the data between pages?
MainPage.xaml
<Page
    x:Class="WinUI3Demo.Pages.MediaCenter.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:WinUI3Demo.Pages.MediaCenter"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d" />

MainPage.xaml.cs
namespace WinUI3Demo.Pages.MediaCenter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public static Frame MainFrame = new();
      
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            MainFrame.Navigate(typeof(MediaCenterPage));
            this.Content = MainFrame;
        }
    }
}

MediaCenterPage.xaml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Page
    x:Class="WinUI3Demo.Pages.MediaCenter.MediaCenterPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:WinUI3Demo.Pages"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:models="using:WinUI3Demo.ViewModels"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Page.DataContext>
        <models:MediaModel x:Name="Model" />
    </Page.DataContext>
    <Grid Padding="16">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="10*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Viewbox Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <TextBlock x:Name="HeaderTextBlock" FontWeight="ExtraBold" />
            </Viewbox>
            <Viewbox
                Grid.Row="0"
                Margin="0,15,0,0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Stretch="UniformToFill">
                <MediaPlayerElement
                    x:Name="MediaPlayer"
                    AreTransportControlsEnabled="False"
                    AutoPlay="True"
                    Source="{x:Bind models:Selected, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </Viewbox>
            <Viewbox Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <TextBlock
                    x:Name="ContentTextBlock"
                    Width="880"
                    TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" />
            </Viewbox>
        </Grid>
        <ScrollView
            Grid.Row="1"
            Height="250"
            Padding="0,10,0,0"
            ContentOrientation="Horizontal">
            <ItemsView
                x:Name="MediaCenterItemView"
                ItemsSource="{x:Bind Model.Objects, Mode=OneWay}"
                PointerPressed="MediaCenterItemView_PointerPressed"
                SelectionChanged="ItemsView_SelectionChanged">
                <ItemsView.Layout>
                    <LinedFlowLayout
                        ItemsStretch="Fill"
                        LineHeight="250"
                        MinItemSpacing="15" />
                </ItemsView.Layout>
                <ItemsView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:MediaObject">
                        <ItemContainer>
                            <Grid>
                                <Image Source="{x:Bind Thumbnail, Mode=OneWay}" Stretch="Uniform" />
                            </Grid>
                        </ItemContainer>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsView.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsView>
        </ScrollView>
    </Grid>
</Page>

MediaCenterPage.xaml.cs
namespace WinUI3Demo.Pages.MediaCenter
{

    public sealed partial class MediaCenterPage : Page
    {
        public static MediaObject SelectedMovie;
        public MediaCenterPage()
        {
         
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ItemsView_SelectionChanged(ItemsView sender, ItemsViewSelectionChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (MediaCenterItemView.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                var selectedMovie = MediaCenterItemView.SelectedItem as MediaObject;
                HeaderTextBlock.Text = selectedMovie.Title;
                ContentTextBlock.Text = selectedMovie.Description;
            }

        }

        private void MediaCenterItemView_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (MediaCenterItemView.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                Frame.Navigate(typeof(PlayerPage));
            }
        }
    }
}

PlayerPage.xaml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Page
    x:Class="WinUI3Demo.Pages.MediaCenter.PlayerPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:WinUI3Demo.Pages"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:models="using:WinUI3Demo.ViewModels"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Page.DataContext>
        <models:MediaModel x:Name="Model" />
    </Page.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <AppBarButton Click="BackButton_Click" Label="Back" />
            <Grid>
                <MediaPlayerElement
                    x:Name="MediaPlayer"
                    AreTransportControlsEnabled="True"
                    AutoPlay="True"
                    Source="{x:Bind , Mode=OneWay}" />
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</Page>

PlayerPage.xaml.cs
namespace WinUI3Demo.Pages.MediaCenter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class PlayerPage : Page
    {
        public PlayerPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void BackButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MainPage.MainFrame.Navigate(typeof(MediaCenterPage));
        }
    }
}

ViewModel//MediaModel.cs
namespace WinUI3Demo.ViewModels
{
    public class MediaModel : ObservableObject
    {
        private ObservableCollection<MediaObject> _objects;
        public ObservableCollection<MediaObject> Objects
        {
            get => _objects;
            set => SetProperty(ref _objects, value);
        }
        private MediaObject _selectedMovie;
        public MediaObject SelectedMovie
        {
            get => _selectedMovie;
            set => SetProperty(ref _selectedMovie, value);
        }

        public MediaModel()
        {
            Objects = new();
        }
        public void AddObject(MediaObject mediaObject)
        {
            Objects.Add(new MediaObject(mediaObject.Filename, mediaObject.Thumbnail, mediaObject.Title, mediaObject.Description, mediaObject.Trailer) { Id = Guid.NewGuid() });
        }
    }


    public class MediaObject : ObservableObject
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Filename { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public BitmapImage Thumbnail { get; set; }
        public MediaSource Trailer { get; set; }
        public MediaSource Movie { get; set; }


        public MediaObject(string _filename, BitmapImage _thumbnail, string _title, string _description, MediaSource _trailer)
        {
            Filename = _filename;
            Thumbnail = _thumbnail;
            Title = _title;
            Description = _description;
            Trailer = _trailer;
            Movie = _trailer;
        }

    }

}


See Frame.Navigate(TypeName, Object) and Page.OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs). Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78291201/winui-how-get-value-from-passed-parameter-by-contentframe-navigate

Thank you for your guidance @YangXiaoPo-MSFT. That worked great. May I ask, what would be the best approach to sharing an observable property which indicated what the selected movie is? Is it okay to have that in the Model? Updated my question so you can see it in MediaModel.cs. Is this the correct MVVM approach? Look at SelectedMovie.

You can make your MainPage have a MediaModel for example MyMediaModel. Then Frame.Navigate(TypeName, MyMediaModel) and set DataContext in Page.OnNavigatedTo of MediaCenterPage and PlayerPage.
Code
public sealed partial class BlankPage1 : Page
{
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        MediaModel m = (MediaModel)e.Parameter;
        DataContext = m;
    }
}

XAML "{x:Bind ((local:MediaModel)DataContext).SelectedMovie}"
But, according to your context, you can only pass the SelectedMovie or a static variable is enough.
